# Use WaitHandle in CountdownEvent

Tags: c#, multithreading, waithandle

I have simple application that illustrates `CountdownEvent`. It is fine, but I would like somehow to set `WaitHandle` of `CountDownEvent` and use it. Is it possible?  How to achieve that? I suppose I should register `WaitHandle` and pass it to `CountDownEvent`?

```
public static CountdownEvent _countDwn = new CountdownEvent(3);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Thread(say).Start("hello 1");
    new Thread(say).Start("hello 2");
    new Thread(say).Start("hello 3");
    _countDwn.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine("done");
    Console.ReadLine();   
}    

public static void Go(object data, bool timedOut)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Started - " + data);
    // Perform task...
}

public static void say(Object o)
{
    Thread.Sleep(4000);
    Console.WriteLine(o);
    _countDwn.Signal(); 
}
```

UPD

I would like to get something similar to sample with `ManualResetEvent`. No blocking `wait()`:

```
static ManualResetEvent _starter = new ManualResetEvent (false);

public static void Main()
{
  RegisteredWaitHandle reg = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject
                             (_starter, Go, "Some Data", -1, true);
  Thread.Sleep (5000);
  Console.WriteLine ("Signaling worker...");
  _starter.Set();
  Console.ReadLine();
  reg.Unregister (_starter);    // Clean up when we’re done.
}

public static void Go (object data, bool timedOut)
{
  Console.WriteLine ("Started - " + data);
  // Perform task...
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the goal? Why\how you want to use `WaitHandle`?

Comment: This is for learning purposes only. Assume I don't want to use blocking wait();

Comment: Well, still have no idea what are you trying to do. Maybe you have some pseudo-code example?

Comment: I expect to pass WaitHandle which will be fired during count down trigger. Updated question  body

Comment: It already wraps a WaitHandle, even exposes it with a public property.  It is a ManualResetEventSlim.  But the property does not have a setter, so you'll have to do this the other way around.  If you want to do it your way then you ought to rewrite the class.  It is not especially difficult, use the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CountdownEvent.cs,01a28a022c3918d1).  Do keep in mind that assigning it is only safe with the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same way you use for `ManualResetEvent`:

```
 RegisteredWaitHandle reg = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject
                         (_countDwn.WaitHandle, Go, "Some Data", -1, true);
 /// ...

 reg.Unregister(_countDwn.WaitHandle);
```